# How can I get a proper double form for a symbolic matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math

How can I get a proper double form from this symbolic Matrix in MatLab? I've tried everything but I prefer not using feval or inline function as they're not recommended

This is the code to get the matrix

```
function T = Romberg (a, b, m, f)

T = zeros(m, m);
T = sym(T);

syms f(x) c h;

f(x) = f;

c = (subs(f,a)+subs(f,b)) / 2;

h = b - a;

T(1,1) = h * c;

som = 0 ;

n = 2;

for i = 2 : m

    h = h / 2;

    for r = 1 : n/2

        som = som + subs(f,(a + 2*(r-1)*h));

        T(i,1) = h * (c + som);

        n = 2*n;

    end

end

r = 1;

for j = 2 : m

    r = 4*r;

    for i = j : m

        T(i,j) = (r * T(i, j-1) - T(i-1,j-1)/(r-1)); 
    end

end

end
```

And with an input like this

```
Romberg(0, 1, 4, '2*x')
```

I get a symbolic matrix output with all the

```
3 * f(3)/2 + f(1)/2 + f(5)/2
```

I would like to have a double output.

Can you please help me?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html)? [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html)?

Comment: I've tried double and vpa but probably I used them in a wrong way... Could you please show me what the code should be like? Thank you

Comment: For example writing "double(T)" at the end of the function but I Always get errors... in this case this one:
``` Error using symengine
DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.
If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use VPA.

Error in sym/double (line 588)
        Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);

Error in Romberg (line 46)
    double(T)
```

Comment: @PaoloVeneziani so.... did you.... try VPA as MATLAB tells you to?

Comment: You get that error because there's no way to convert expressions like `f(3)` to a floating point number unless you know what `f` is.